# Using a list as a generic

Tags: java

Why does this not compile?

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> myMap;
myMap = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
```

With the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>> to
Map<Integer,List<String>>
```

Why can't I use a generic as a generic?

It's not like I'm asking the difference between `List<Dog>` and `List<Animal>`. Contract between `List<String>` and `ArrayList<String>` should match.

Comment: Because `List<String>` is not the same as `ArrayList<String>` in the generic declaration.

Comment: After reading the possible duplicate Q/A, you should understand the difference between `List<Dog>` and `List<Animal>`. Now, from the same example, replace `Dog` by `List<Whatever>` and replace `Animal` by `ArrayList<Whatever>`. Then you got your answer.

Comment: `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();` is not a subtype of (nor is it convertible to) `Map<Integer, List<String>>` and is therefore not assignable to it.

Comment: General rule of thumb:  Only specify the implementing type of a `List`/`Map` when you're creating said list/map.  In this case, you're creating the `HashMap`, but not the `ArrayList`.